# is it possible to use the preprocessor __file__ to generate a #define in C?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

In order to improve the aesthetics of some code, I would like to have a .h file contain some code that sets a #define based on which file the .h file is included from.  For example

```
#if (__file__ == "main.c")
#define MOUDLE MODULE_MAIN
#elif (__file__ == "foo.c")
#define MODULE MODULE_FOO
#endif
```

Is there any way to accomplish something like this?  The main motivation is to avoid putting a #define MODULE at the top of every file and instead have one location where the mapping is defined and to just include the same .h file.

Comment: "Is there any way to accomplish something like this?" - have you tried doing this? Did it work?

Comment: What is the result of the posted code?

Comment: Take a look here, by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path

Comment: It's `__FILE__`, not `__file__`. And you misspelled "MOUDLE".

Comment: @ForceBru No, that code does not work for a couple reasons, but since you are a human and not a C compiler you should be able to understand what it means. Presumably, that's why reza asked the question.

Comment: @reza Note that `__FILE__` will give the name of the `.h` file. For GCC, you can use `__BASE_FILE__` to get the name of the `.c` file on the command line, but that isn't portable to different compilers. Either way, [as melpomene says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927674/27302), the preprocessor can't decide things based on that string.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this. `#if` can only do integer expressions. It knows nothing about strings or how to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is **not possible** with the standard C preprocessor. Check by reading the C standard, eg [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), or some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), or the [wikipage on the C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), or the [GNU `cpp` manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

But consider another way to achieve the same: configure *appropriately* your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation).

For example, if you use [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), then edit your `Makefile` appropriately. How to do that is a very different question.

You could have a rule for `make` which passes a specific `-DMODULE=`*name* to `gcc`

For example in my [`bismon` (on github)](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) the [`Makefile`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/Makefile) has near line [141](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/Makefile#L141) something similar to

```
modules/modbm_%.so: modules/modbm_%.c bismon.h  $(GENERATED_HEADERS) $(BM_HEADERS)
   $(CCACHE) $(LINK.c) -fPIC \
      -DBISMON_MODID=$(patsubst modules/modbm_%.c,_%,$<) -shared $< -o $@
```

*Be creative*. The build machinery is part of your source code. Adapt it to do what you want. Don't expect the standard preprocessor to cover all your needs. Learn how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) (or your favorite compiler) on the [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). In [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829773/841108), it is even worthwhile to *generate* some C file (perhaps some header file), and you might use *another* preprocessor (like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or m4) for that purpose.

Remember that the compiler (notably [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) is a command line program, that you should drive from something else (like  [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/) or many other build automation tools).

<sup>(even on microsoft systems the compiler is still a command line thing, but that fact is often ignored)</sup>

BTW, I dislike many [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s because they are *hiding* the build process, and you need to master it. So you need to configure it (e.g. by writing your `Makefile` or something else) and to understand and tailor it.

> The main motivation is to avoid putting a `#define MODULE` at the top of every file and instead have one location where the mapping is defined

That single location defining such a mapping should probably be your build infrastructure (e.g. your `Makefile` if using `make`); you'll adapt it to invoke `gcc` or `clang` (or most other C compilers) with an appropriate `-DMODULE=`*name* flag. (BTW, you also want the *convention* that your base name of sources files are C identifiers, so you won't have any `a-1.c` file -since `a-1` is not an identifier-,  but a `bcde.c` one).

If using GNU `make`, read its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), then run `make -p` to understand the rules (both builtin, and custom) relevant to your case. Then consider perhaps a rule similar to:

```
%.o: %.c $(YOURHEADERS)
     $(COMPILE.c) -DMODULE=$(patsubst %.c,MODULE_%,$^) -c $< -o $@
```

but *adapt that rule* to your needs. (you could need some `$(shell` ... `)` inside it if your file names are lower cases, and you want upper case `MODULE`).

BTW, you could also generate parts of your `Makefile` (or have some *generated* C files, which you would `#include` appropriately).

Comment: The C standard is long and not written to be a reference guide for programmers, and recommending people read it without even pointing to the preprocessor section (6.10, with 6.10.1 specifically for conditionals) is not very helpful. It's more helpful to link to a reference for programmers like [cppreference, which despite the name has sections which are C references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional).

Comment: Indeed, but the authoritative reference is still the C standard