# Create unique objects from string literals in multiple places

Tags: c++

My project contains lots of string literals for which I need to store some other properties as well (like a fnv1a hash for example).

- I want these strings (together with other meta information) to be stored as global (const) objects of type `UniqueString`.
- I want to inspect the objects using ELF tools, so the constants should be really there
- There should be only one instance per content, even though the same string literal may be used in many places. Some kind of deduplication.
- I want the string literal in the caller location to be optimized away
- It's an embedded project without heap

I tried the following which does obviously not work:

```cpp
// uniquestring.h
template<char... letters>
struct UniqueString
{
    static constexpr size_t length = sizeof...(letters);
    static constexpr char storage[length] = {letters...};
    // may contain more stuff
};

template<char... letters>
constexpr auto makeUniqueString(const char* string);

template<char... letters>
constexpr auto makeUniqueString(const char* string)
{
    switch(string[0]) {
    case '\0':
        return UniqueString<letters..., '\0'>::storage; // termination
    case 'A':
        return makeUniqueString<letters..., 'A'>(&string[1]);
    // all other letters if necessary
    default:
        return (const char*)nullptr;
    }
}

// file1.cpp
#include "uniquestring.h"
void someFunction() {
    // We have only implemented the A case, so let's use a simple string
    const char* result = makeUniqueString("AAA");
}

// file2.cpp
#include "uniquestring.h"
void someOtherFunction() {
    const char* result = makeUniqueString("AAA");
}

// this should result in one UniqueString type stored as a constant in my application binary.
```

G++ says `fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900`. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: "There should be only one instance per content, even though the same string literal may be used in many places. Some kind of deduplication." - it's already there - "string pooling".

Comment: You might be interested by [string-interning-at-compiletime-for-profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289055/2684539)

Comment: I would try to use source pre-processing for that (even is it is far from trivial...)