# How to convert a string literal to a character sequence and assign it to a template class's parameter pack char... C in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14

For example, I have a template struct String that accepts a parameter pack of characters.

```
template<char ...pack>
struct String{}
```

How can I implement the code to make String<"abcd"> legal?

Comment: Not possible. Best you can do before C++20 is `"abcd"_foo`, and that can only be made to work on GCC and Clang, not MSVC, using non-standard extensions.

Comment: Why do you need this? Or better what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I want to implement a compile-time String type that helps me concatenate ordinary strings into more complex strings at compile-time using a certain logic. Constructing a "abc" string with String<'a', 'b', 'c'> can be cumbersome, so I hope to be able to use a syntax like String<"abc"> to directly construct a String type from a string literal instead of a sequence of characters.

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289055/2684539) provides code to have either a MACRO `MAKE_STRING` to transform literal string as char-sequence or udl thanks to non-stadard gcc/clang extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constexpr functions to do what you want to do.
Like this :

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
struct ce_string_t final
{
    ce_string_t() = default;
    ~ce_string_t() = default;

    explicit constexpr ce_string_t(const char(&str)[N])
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(str), std::end(str), m_buf.begin());
    }

    constexpr char operator[](const std::size_t i) const noexcept
    {
        return m_buf[i];
    }

private:
    
    template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
    friend static constexpr auto operator+(const ce_string_t<N>& str1, const ce_string_t<M>& str2);

    std::array<char, N + 1> m_buf{};

};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
static constexpr auto operator+(const ce_string_t<N>& str1, const ce_string_t<M>& str2)
{
    ce_string_t<N + M> result{};
    for(std::size_t i{0ul}; i < N; ++i) result.m_buf[i] = str1.m_buf[i];
    for(std::size_t i{0ul}; i < M; ++i) result.m_buf[i+N-1] = str2.m_buf[i];
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr ce_string_t str1{ "abc" };
    static constexpr ce_string_t str2{ "def" };
    static constexpr auto str3 = str1 + str2;

    static_assert(str3[0] == 'a');
    static_assert(str3[1] == 'b');
    static_assert(str3[2] == 'c');
    static_assert(str3[3] == 'd');
    static_assert(str3[4] == 'e');
    static_assert(str3[5] == 'f');
    static_assert(str3[6] == 0);
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It mainly depends how/where OP uses the string... `ce_string_t<N>` content still can't be used as constant expression when passed as argument.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I know... and probably in C++20 std::string is supposed ot be mainly constexpr too. So it also depends on what version C++ OP can use. I think my main point is that it is probably better to look for constexpr stuff than it is to look for variadic template solutions