# Convert string literal into char parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm learning a bit of metaprogramming in modern C++ and I'm trying to implement a class that should represent string literals/static strings or whatever those are called, in a compile time type. I've managed to get this to work, and I've tried to add some basic compile time operations I want to do with those static strings. Here's the code:

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, T... cs>
class static_string;

template<typename T, T... cs>
constexpr static_string<T, cs...> make_static_string() {
    return {};
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_static_string(const T(&str)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return static_string<T, str[Is]...>();
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto make_static_string(const T(&str)[N]) {
    return make_static_string(str, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

template<typename T, T... cs>
class static_string 
{
    constexpr static std::array<T, sizeof...(cs)> s_data{ cs... };

public:
    constexpr static std::basic_string_view<T> value{ s_data.data(), sizeof...(cs) };
};

template<typename T, T... tlhs, T... trhs>
constexpr auto operator+([[maybe_unused]] static_string<T, tlhs...> lhs, [[maybe_unused]] static_string<T, trhs...> rhs) noexcept -> static_string<T, tlhs..., trhs...> {
    return {};
}

template <typename T, T... tlhs, size_t N>
constexpr auto operator+(static_string<T, tlhs...> lhs, const T (&rhs)[N]) noexcept {
    return lhs + make_static_string(rhs);
}

template <typename T, T... trhs, size_t N>
constexpr auto operator+(const T (&lhs)[N], static_string<T, trhs...> rhs) noexcept {
    return make_static_string(lhs) + rhs;
}

template<typename T, T... cs>
constexpr auto operator""_ss() -> static_string<T, cs...> {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << ("Hello"_ss + "World").value;

    return 0;
}
```

With this code I'm able to concatenate literals when I explicitly convert them to my `static_string` type. However I find that a bit annoying to add my custom string literal operator. I would like to be able to concatenate also my `static_string` with plain string literals, like `"World"` in code above.

However I'm struggling with how to convert plain string literal to the parameter pack for my type. This is the problematic part of the code:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_static_string(const T(&str)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return static_string<T, str[Is]...>();
}
```

because `str[Is]...` cannot really be expanded, as it is not a constant expression. How can one do this properly?

Thanks

Comment: Function arguments value are never `constexpr`...

Comment: MACRO can help with some limit, see [`MAKE_STRING` from my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289055/2684539).

Comment: Every string literal is `const T(&str)[N]` but not every `const T(&str)[N]` is a string literal!